# John is calling you or John's calling you

Tags: punctuation

Is there a difference between “John is calling” and “John’s calling”?

I mean, can I use an apostrophe and an “s” after John’s name in the above context, and be understood as “John is calling”?

If both have the same meaning, then can I write "cat's an animal" in place of "cat is an animal"?

Comment: So, can I write "cat's an animal" in place of "cat is an animal"?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is exactly the same.  The **'s** is just a contraction of **is**.  [The version with the contraction, *John's calling*, is less formal.](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/12/contractions-in-formal-writing-whats-allowed-whats-not.html)

Answer (score 0):

the **'s** is a contraction of the word **is**. The two sentences are virtually the same.

contraction [link](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/grammar/contractions/1/)

> A contraction is a word made by shortening and combining two words.
>   Words like can't (can + not), don't (do + not), and I've (I + have)
>   are all contractions. People use contractions in both speaking and
>   writing.

Comment: I previously thought that an apostrophe and an “s” after a noun denotes only possessions. Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: @SyedAhmed I have had trouble with the use of possessions. Its was drummed into me, but John's dog? It doesn't mean John is dog. When the names ends in an 's', I lose my mind. The dog belongs to the Jones. It's the Jones'/ Jones's dog. Ugh!